# potential energy in vertical motion.

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy

> A ball of mass $m$ is moving inside a vertical hollow hoop with radius $L$ and with angular velocity $\omega$.

[image]

I was asked to find a term for the total potential energy of the ball.

Intuitively, I thought of the term $u=mgL(1-cos\theta )$ since when $\theta=0$ I expect it to be $0$ and when $\theta=180$ to be $2mgL$.

Can someone help me understand if and why this term works? how can I get to it with looking on the energy in the system?

Comment: Hint: the gravitational potential energy near Earth's surface is $U = mg(y-y_0)$, where the constant $y_0$ is chosen arbitrarily. Set up both a Cartesian coordinate grid and a polar coordinate grid that share their origin at the center of the loop. What is $y$ for a particle on the loop expressed in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Gravitational potential energy = meh